# MUC Room Chat History using Strophe.js web client and MongooseIM As XMPP server

Tags: xmpp, multiuserchat, mongoose-im, strophe.js

I am currently struggling to get Chat Histroy of a MUCLight Room using Strophe.js. I dont want to use the direct MUC plugin. I have used the below approaches:-

Sending the below IQ, but no return in the callback:-

```
<iq type='set' id='mamget1' to='coven@muclight.shakespeare.lit'>
    <query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:1' queryid='f27' />
</iq>
```

Sending the below presence but Handler not receiving anything:-

```
<presence from="jid" id="9855" to="roomJID" xmlns="jabber:client">
<x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc">
<history maxstanzas="20"/>
</x>
</presence>
```

Please tell the correct approach,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

MUC Light's history works only with MAM. MAM is not enabled by default on the server, though. Could you make sure relevant modules are enabled? I recommend using the newest MongooseIM from [1] as MAM configuration was significantly simplified there. The documentation about MAM config is here [2].

If you use MongooseIM 2.0.0 or older, please choose relevant doc version in bottom left corner on mongooseim.readthedocs.io

---

[1]. https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM 
[2]. http://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/mod_mam

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply but i have already enabled the mod_mam,  mod_muclight. I am able to confirm it by using disco#info iq sent to my XMPP server, the server returns all the implemente features there along with "urn:xmpp:mam:1" , which is the mam module for muc-light.

Comment: Would you mind sharing you ejabberd.cfg file? At least `modules` section so I can see how exactly they are configured. Also, does MAM work for one-to-one messages?